Как сохранить состояние авторизации в скрипте instagrapi, избежать бана и добавлять посты для выгрузки по требованию?
Использую библиотеку instagrapi для выгрузки постов по времени. При активации скрипта авторизация.ру происходит вход в аккаунт и последующая выгрузка постов. Если слишком часто активировать скрипт есть вероятность бана. Отсюда вытекает вопрос:
Как реализовать систему где скрипт будет в состояний "авторизованный" но при этом, останется возможность в любое время добавить необходимые посты для выгрузки через другой скрипт, например...
Мои бедный ум придумал нечто такое:
Есть 2 файла
1 авторизация.ру - для авторизации на сайте. Файл висит и не завершается
2 выгрузка.ру - для выгрузки постов авторизация идет через авторизация.ру
Скрипт будет на сервере.
import time
from instagrapi import Client
from instagrapi.types import StoryMention, StoryMedia, StoryLink, StoryHashtag
import config

cl = Client()
try:
            cl.login(config.username, config.password)
            print("Вход произведен успешно")
except:
            print("Не удалось войти в аккаунт")

            
my_file = config.photo
my_file2 = config.photo2

cl.photo_upload_to_story(
            path = my_file,
            )
print('success1')

time.sleep(60)

cl.photo_upload_to_story(
            path = my_file2,
            )

print('success2')


А почему нельзя сделать это все в одной программе? Создаете сессию, авторизуетесь и пусть висит. В папку рядом с ней можно класть разметку для постов (например json-файл, в котором будет указано, как назвать пост, какой текст/картинки прикрепить и так далее). Потом, программа, которая инициировала, авторизацию может по таймеру загружать по очереди эти файлы и отгружать их в сеть. Если файлов новых в папке не оказалось, можно реализовать отправку какого-нибудь уведомления об ошибке. Хотя соединение с api может и оборваться по различным причинам, нужно сделать возможность восстановить его вновь

Можно конечно создать что-то вроде демона, который будет хранить сессию и выступать посредником между api и программами, желающими получить к нему доступ. Но если ваша цель - грузить посты в один единственный аккаунт, то такая конструкция, как мне кажется, будет излишней

Спасибо за ответ. Я собираюсь делать это не для одного аккаунта и не для одного поста. Возможно, через телеграм бота для удобства. Посему существует потребность реализовать это "по уму"
